# c# 2D auto expandable collection

Tags: c#, collections, set, 2d, abstraction

I'm looking for a collection.

I need to be able to add elements as if using a 2D integer key, for example `.Add(3, 4, element)`. If I add outside the range of the collection I need the collection to expand, this include negatively, although it can have a limit, for example the range of an Int16 would be good. Every element in the collection can have the same type as each other but I need to specify what that is, for example `Set<type> s;`

I also need to avoid slow operations such as searching when looking up an element, performance is less important when adding to the collection.

Does anyone have any ideas about what approach to use or best could provide the class in there answer.

Comment: do you want to add the same "key" values more than once? Ie: would you ever get the scenario .Add(3, 4) then .Add(3, 5) then .Add(3, 6) for instance? If so Dictionary<T1, T2> won't work as T1 values must be unique

Comment: Sorry. I've rewored it :¬P `.Add(3, 4, element)`

Comment: What you want is a sparse matrix collection. You keep a list of index pairs using a `Tuple<int,int>` and a list of values.

Comment: If you think you can improve on Steve B, feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a compound key, you can use the [`Tuple<T1,T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267681.aspx) class in a : `Dictionary<Tuple<T1,T2>, TItem>`.

```
var coll = new Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>, AnyClass>();
coll.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(2, 3), new AnyClass("foo"));
coll.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(4, 2), new AnyClass("bar"));

var foo = coll[new Tuple<int,int>(2,3)];
var bar = coll[new Tuple<int,int>(4,2)];
```

If the syntax is too weird, you may wrap the class like this :

```
public class Dictionary2d<TKey1, TKey2, TItem> : Dictionary<Tuple<TKey1, TKey2>,TItem>
{
    public void Add(TKey1 k1, TKey2, TItem item) {
        this.Add(Tuple.Create(k1,k2), item);
    }

    public TItem this[TKey1 k1, TKey2 k2] {
        get { return this[Tuple.Create(k1,k2)]; }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main() {
        var coll = new Dictionary2d<int,int, AnyClass>();
        coll.Add(2, 3, new AnyClass("foo"));
        coll.Add(4, 2, new AnyClass("bar"));

        var foo = coll[2,3];
        var bar = coll[4,2];
    }
}
```

The benefits of using Tuple class, is that the equality and hashcode comparison is natively handled, so even if it's a class, two differents instances of tuple with same values will be considered equals.

Comment: I can't see how the TContent line works and it won't compile. I think it's supposed to be TItem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a `Dictionary<int, T>`.

Comment: (sorry, I edited stuff into my question just after posting) Does a Dictionary require that all elements are searched when looking up an answer?

Comment: @alan2here No, a Dictionary is of O(1), so it is very efficient.

Comment: @alan2here It means the system must perform only 1 lookup (generally) per element rather than iterate over a list.

Comment: Thanks. I've just read the wiki article and yes, it appears it is that good. So am I right in thinking that (ignoring the extra layer of abstraction required in his) this is twice as fast as Roy Dictus answer?

Comment: If performance is so important, make sure you set the initial capacity of the dictionary big enough. Otherwise, the dictionary will have to keep expanding, which hurts insert times.

Comment: @alan2here:  Roy's answer is a nested dictionary; it uses two keys.

Comment: Thanks, thats handy to know, although insert times don't matter much and I don't know in advance how big it will need to be, only lookup times matter.

Comment: Ahh, yes. I was imagining that this answer required a class for the int of the dictonary that contained two ints anyway.

Comment: @alan2here: Correct.  Using a key class (such as `Tuple`) is probably faster than a nested dictionary, but I haven't measured.

Comment: Then Steve B answer wins, also at least to me that way round is more conceptually pleasing :¬) and in a way yours does as well because his idea extends yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this `Set<T>` by storing its data in a private variable of type `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, T>>`.

You can then store using

```
public void Add(int key1, int key2, T value)
{
    _storage[key1][key2] = value;
}
```

Comment: You need to check that the inner dictionary exists.  Use `TryGetValue`.

Comment: Of course the inner dictionary exists, _storage is a private variable and is managed entirely by the Set<T> class.

Comment: I mean make sure that `_storage[key1]` exists